# html - px and % width setting conflict in IE and Mozilla

Tags: css, html

all i am doing is a simple - creating a html page. however, i got 2 probs.

1) when i set the width in pixels:
i see width mismatch/conflict between IE8 and mozilla. (width:1024px)
this setting sets the width perfectly in mozilla (full screen size) but in IE, it exceeds the page/screen width and i have to scroll to the right to see some part of the page.

sample code:

html:

```
<div style="width:1024px">
```

2) when i set the width in percentage and resize the window:
the page shrinks and the whole page gets collapsed.

below is the code.

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#">something</a>
        <a href="#">something1</a>
        <a href="#">something2</a>
        <a href="#">something3</a>
        <a href="#">something4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.body
{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    background:grey;
    float:left;
} 

.header
{
    float:left;
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
```

how can i overcome this small glitch?
any help is appreciated.

Comment: For 1024 resolution, you have to give width :1000px

Comment: thala, can u pls provide a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a reset style sheet, or add the following to the css:

```
body,
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally,Internet explorer(lower version) browser scroll bar take some pixels. Just u put width 1000px or 100%, because 100% width all resolution and screen sizes appear full screen without scroll.

I think no need body and header `float: left`

Comment: well, float is used here to keep all the a href elements in the same line. if we remove that, it comes one below the other. any other suggestion?

Comment: only you fix anchor tag in float: left. Not put header and body.

Comment: thx.. but if i put width in percent - that will fit to the screen in any resolution, thats rt.. but when i resize the window, the contents get collapsed..